Which one to chose among array library and numpy to write to disk
I need to produce a python program to save a large amount of vectors on disk. I receive the data as fixed-length list[float].
I have several idea regarding the method to save them in memory.
using json :
import json

def save_to_json(data, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

using built-in array:
import array

def save_with_array(data, file_name):
    arr = array.array('d', data)
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
        arr.tofile(file)

or using numpy:
import numpy as np

def save_with_numpy(data, file_name):
    np_array = np.array(data, dtype=np.float64)
    np_array.tofile(file_name)

The ideal method is the fastest, and if it's low on memory, it's a plus.
From my tests, the binary file produced by numpy and array are identical, so I guess they use the same process under the hood, but maybe one is faster than the other.
Regarding json, this was my first idea, but I feel it is not suited for this use case.
Any idea how to optimize the process ?

Json is generally not efficient for that, and indeed not suited for such use-case. Numpy should be relatively good and quite standard. An alternative is you use HDF5 files. It is more standard in the scientific community, provide more feature and might be more efficient in some cases (it supports compression and the packing of many array).

As for Numpy vs array, AFAIK the main (only?) difference is that Numpy should use a different header (this is only few bytes at the beginning). If they turn out to be equal, this is certainly by pure luck. AFAIK, array does not use the Numpy standard (which is defined in the Numpy documentation).

what data type is data?

Note that (once excluded high-level formats, like json, and focusing on formats that just dump the raw data) "speed" is not very well defined here. It depends on other things. If you have a very fast disk, and a not so fast CPU, .npy (or your .tofile, which is the same, but without a header) may be better. If you have a fast cpu and a slow drive (or even a remote one), then maybe .npz (np.savez("file.npz", arr=arr)) is better That is using cpu time to compress the data, which saves some bandwidth / bitrate to save them. It also depends on the data (eg pure random cannot be compressed)

So, point is, it is hard to answer to "which is the best" (generally speaking those question are not very well received on [SO], because they lead to subjective answers)

Thank you very much for all your very informative answers. @chrslg, I know this type of questions may lead to subjective answers (even though every answer is necessarily subjective), but I think all the comments above give valuable hints and tips on how to do what I want to do.
